# Excel dynamic link within Sheet

Tags: excel

I have two columns A and B.  column B data are supposedly refer to column A data (column A data are unique ).

I need to create a hyperlink in column B in a way if its clicked it should highlight its value in column A.

I can do it manually (right click --> Hyperlink and etc).

But is there an efficient way to create a **hyperlink** in which if I click on column B data it takes me to where the data is in column A?

```
A    B
1    2
2    5 
3    4
4    5
5    2
....
```

Example :
Click on B value 5 and it highlights value 5 in column A?

Comment: What is the formula inside of the B column? Is it a direct reference? Or is it a complex formula that looks something up and pulls a value from column A? I see that there are multiple times where B = "2" or "5". This implies that it is not a direct reference.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon there is no complex formula in neither A or B,

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you simply use the standard keyboard shortcut CTRL + [. This takes you to the spot where a formula comes from (it references the first cell used in the formula). To see where a formula ends up (on the same page), use CTRL + ].

Avoid using mouseclicks for things like this; moving to use only the keyboard as much as possible will make you more efficient in the long run.

Also - you can change your excel settings under EXCEL > OPTIONS > ADVANCED and uncheck 'allow editing directly in cells'; this will make it so that clicking on a cell will take you there, instead of opening the edit window (which you can instead access by pressing f2, or clicking the formula bar).

Comment: Note that while I answered this question it is not really suited for this site; it is better suited to Superuser.com, which focuses on software use other-than coding.